# training when Multiple labels per image

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I have multiple labels per image. is it better to train taking each each label separately or should i mark all the labels present as 1 in the same image? which method is better? i will be using CNN architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to classify the images (and not use bounding boxes to *locate* classes within each image), a common way it to create a target *vector* for each image, which holds the information regarding all classes and is what the model would eventually predict.

If you have a dataset with, say 5 classes, and your first example image contains classes 1 and 4, you would create your target vector for that image to be:

```
example_sample = ... # your image array
example_sample_y = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

This is a kind of [one-hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f), as the vector has a placeholder for each of the 5 classes, but only a `1` when the class is present.

Have a look at this [high-level walkthrough](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-image-classification-with-inception-net-cbb2ee538e30).

---

I think your other suggestion of training an image

You want to learn some kind of joint probability between the classes, and in my opinion, training one the same image with different outcomes (e.g. the sample image above twice, producing either a 1 or a 4) will not only be very inefficient during training, but will also be mathematically confusing. The same input can give 2 possible outputs! This implies your underlying function that maps images to classes is not [well-defined](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Well-Defined.html). That isn't usually a good thing!